# getting values using Boolean field in hibernate

Tags: hibernate, hql

I am using postgres and I have a table as follows,

```
    CREATE TABLE entity_transaction
    (
      id bigint NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('entity_transactionid_seq'::regclass),
      transaction_ref character varying(11) NOT NULL,
      transaction_type character varying(10) NOT NULL,
      is_remitted boolean DEFAULT false);
```

I created a model class as follows for that table.

```
    @Entity
    @Table(name = "entity_transaction")
    public class Transaction implements Serializable {

        private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

        @Id
        @Column(name = "id")
        Long id;

        @Column(name = "transaction_ref")
        String transactionRef;

        @Column(name = "transaction_type")
        String transactionType;

        @Column(name = "is_remitted")
        Boolean isRemitted;
```

I am just trying to get the values from that table using "isRemitted" filed is true or false. For this I am trying the following query

```
    @Repository(value = "collectionsRepositary")
    public class CollectionsRepositoryImpl implements CollectionsRepository {

        @Resource
        private SessionFactory sessionFactory;

        @Override
        public List<Transaction> getUnmatchedList() {
            Query query = createQuery("select t from Transaction where t.transactionType = 'c' and t.isRemitted is true");      
            return query.list();
        }

        public Query createQuery(String queryString) {
            return getSession().createQuery(queryString);
        }

        private Session getSession() {
            return sessionFactory.getCurrentSession();
        }
    }
```

But I am unable to get the values, which was returning empty list. There is datas available in that table with this boolean value and transactionType.

Can anyone give me a right way in this?

thanks in advance,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure about this but `is true` sounds special to me.
I think your query should work with `= true`.

EDIT: I'm sorry, I didn't see that, your query should look like this:

```
select t from Transaction t where t.transactionType = 'c' and t.isRemitted = true
```

instead of this:

```
select t from Transaction t.transactionType = 'c' and t.isRemitted is true
```

The `where` is missing.

Comment: Ok, so what does `convertToCollectionsDTO` do. And i think you have a typo in `@Repository(value = "collectionsRepositary")`, shouldn't it be Reposit**o**ry?

Comment: No... Its for other purpose... So I just not included here.. I updated the question.. Pls take a look again..

Answer (score 0):

Check for generated query; Hibernate should maps `java.lang.Boolean` as BIT and probably a PG `boolean` is intendend not to be a BIT but a similar (but different) type (like a TINYINT, for example).
As my experience I have always mapped boolean fields with a tinyiny or a custom type; check on SO.